# Prevent application requiring LED or camera flash from Android marketplace

Tags: android, marketplace

Is there a particular flag that we can use to prevent apps 
showing up in marketplace which require the phone to have a camera 
flash /LED? Typical apps are ones which make the phone act like a 
torchlight in dark. I have seen a tag which prevents apps requiring 
autofocus in a camera from appearing in the marketplace.

Just looking to find out if there is something similar for camera 
flash.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were the one who asked, but this popped up on [android-developers] recently. Dianne Hackborn pointed out that there is a `<uses-feature>` element for this: `android.hardware.camera.flash`.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file you would need to add:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

From what I have read you need to specify camera and autofocus before flash.

Just wondering, have you had any luck turning on the led on an un-rooted phone?